# ReactJs Lazy loading with conditional

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, mobx

Hello I'm in trouble with how I can load my components using asynchronous calls
Basically when opening the page I check my api if the user has any valid token (it is active), if it is not active the login page will be rendered if not the dashboard page will be rendered
But this caused me a problem, when I am not connected everything is normal the login page is shown without problems, but when I am connected before showing the dashboard page it renders the login page, and I am in a dilemma of how resolve this

**APP:**

```
const LoginPage = lazy(
  () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "LoginPage" */ './pages/login'),
);
const DashBoard = lazy(
  () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "DashBoard" */ './shared/infra/router'),
);
const AuthApp: React.FC<{isAuth: boolean; currentUser: any}> = observer(
  ({currentUser, isAuth}) => {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading profile...</h1>}>
        {isAuth && currentUser ? <DashBoard /> : <LoginPage />}
      </Suspense>
    );
  },
);

const App: React.FC = observer(() => {
  const {currentUserStore, authStore, layoutStore} = useRootStore();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUserStore.accessToken || !authStore.isAuth) authStore.initApi();
  });
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={layoutStore.isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <GlobalReset />
      <AuthApp
        isAuth={authStore.isAuth}
        currentUser={currentUserStore.currentUser}
      />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
});

export default App;
```

**API Call**: I am using MOBX with RootStore

```
  public initApi = async (): Promise<void> => {
    this.rootStore.authStore.inProgress = true;
    try {
      await this.rootStore.AxiosStore.get('/')
        .then((res) => {
          const decoded: any = jwtDecode(res.data.access_token);
          runInAction(() => {
            if (!(decoded instanceof Error)) {
              this.rootStore.currentUserStore.accessToken =
                res.data.access_token;
              this.rootStore.currentUserStore.currentUser = new UserModel({
                ...decoded,
                id: decoded.sub,
              });
            }
          });
        })
        .then(() =>
          runInAction(() => {
            this.rootStore.authStore.isAuth = true;
          }),
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      const mute = error;
      runInAction(() => {
        this.rootStore.authStore.isAuth = false;
      });
    } finally {
      runInAction(() => {
        this.rootStore.authStore.inProgress = false;
      });
    }
  };
```

not logged gif:

[image]

logged gif:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this behavior because your effect in your `App` component runs every time the component renders. If you only want to run the effect once after the initial render you can give it an empty array as second argument.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!currentUserStore.accessToken || !authStore.isAuth) authStore.initApi();
}, []);
```